# Problems with sum of objects in array with React

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate the total sum of "stopTime" in this object.

I have some problems resolving this, I have searched far and wide without any success.
My API response looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "stopCause": "Stop Cause 1",
        "stopTime": 3,
        "stopOperator": "Somebody",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:31.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:31.000Z",
        "OrderId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "stopCause": "Stop Cause 3",
        "stopTime": 5,
        "stopOperator": "Somebody",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:37.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:37.000Z",
        "OrderId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "stopCause": "Stop Cause 4",
        "stopTime": 12,
        "stopOperator": "Username",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-28T06:45:24.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-28T06:45:24.000Z",
        "OrderId": 1
    }
]
```

and here is the code to sum up "stopTime" :

```
const totalStopTime = stopTime.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr.stopTime),
    0
  );
```

This would all work fine and dandy if there wasn't any delay from the API call... It always resolves into 0, because the API is slower than the page loading...

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Then, wait for the response and then do calculations... whats the problem?

Comment: `async/await` sounds familiar?

Comment: It sounds like (in code you're not showing us) you're trying to use the result of an asynchronous operation before that operation has completed.  This has nothing to do with React, arrays, objects, sums, or anything else being asked about in the question.  Can you provide an example which demonstrates the problem you describe?

Comment: Wait for the response...

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with API responses you should use async/await to resolve issues due to such asynchronous responses. You need to change your code structure to something like this:

```js
function simulateAPICall() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const apiResponse = [
        {
          id: 1,
          stopCause: 'Stop Cause 1',
          stopTime: 3,
          stopOperator: 'Somebody',
          createdAt: '2023-06-26T10:29:31.000Z',
          updatedAt: '2023-06-26T10:29:31.000Z',
          OrderId: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          stopCause: 'Stop Cause 3',
          stopTime: 5,
          stopOperator: 'Somebody',
          createdAt: '2023-06-26T10:29:37.000Z',
          updatedAt: '2023-06-26T10:29:37.000Z',
          OrderId: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          stopCause: 'Stop Cause 4',
          stopTime: 12,
          stopOperator: 'Username',
          createdAt: '2023-06-28T06:45:24.000Z',
          updatedAt: '2023-06-28T06:45:24.000Z',
          OrderId: 1,
        },
      ];
      resolve(apiResponse);
    }, 2000); 
  });
}

async function fetchData() {

  const response = await simulateAPICall();

  const totalStopTime = response.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr.stopTime),
    0
  );

  console.log('Total Stop Time:', totalStopTime);
}

fetchData();
```

The call to `simulateAPICall()` function should be replaced by the actual API call.

Basically, due to the `await` keyword before api call, the control waits for the assignment before moving forward making that part synchronous-like.
Note that `await` can only be used inside an `async` function.

Read more about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your fetch call but in general you can't await for an `asynchronous` call in React. You need to do a little bit of a hack with `useEffect` to populate some state with `useState`. You can then use the state to trigger a `useMemo` to conditionally calculate some operation (i.e., `Array.reduce()`)

```js
import { useMemo, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const timerData = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "stopCause": "Stop Cause 1",
        "stopTime": 3,
        "stopOperator": "Somebody",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:31.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:31.000Z",
        "OrderId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "stopCause": "Stop Cause 3",
        "stopTime": 5,
        "stopOperator": "Somebody",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:37.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:37.000Z",
        "OrderId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "stopCause": "Stop Cause 4",
        "stopTime": 12,
        "stopOperator": "Username",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-28T06:45:24.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-28T06:45:24.000Z",
        "OrderId": 1
    }
]
const Example = () => {
    const [stopTime, setStopTime] = useState()
    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchStopTime = async () => {
            const response =  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, timerData));
            setStopTime(response)
        }
        fetchStopTime()
    }, [])

    
    const totalStopTime = useMemo(()=>{
        if(stopTime === undefined) return 0
        return (
            stopTime.reduce(
                (acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr.stopTime),
                0
              )
        )
    }, [stopTime])

    return (
        <div>
            {totalStopTime}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Example
```

If you use `fetch` then you can replace the `fetchStopTime` function with

```js
const fetchStopTime = async () => {
   const response =  await fetch('some_api_url')
   const data = await response.json()
   setStopTime(data)
}
```

**Here's an snippet where the code had to be modified because stack overflow snippet library ES2015 doesn't support async functions. The code above follows conventions developers are familiar with**

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useMemo} = React;
const timerData = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "stopCause": "Stop Cause 1",
        "stopTime": 3,
        "stopOperator": "Somebody",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:31.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:31.000Z",
        "OrderId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "stopCause": "Stop Cause 3",
        "stopTime": 5,
        "stopOperator": "Somebody",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:37.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-26T10:29:37.000Z",
        "OrderId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "stopCause": "Stop Cause 4",
        "stopTime": 12,
        "stopOperator": "Username",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-28T06:45:24.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-28T06:45:24.000Z",
        "OrderId": 1
    }
]

const Example = ({title}) => {
    const [stopTime, setStopTime] = useState()
    useEffect(()=>{
          const fetchStopTime = () => {
              new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, timerData))
          .then(response => setStopTime(response))          
          }
          fetchStopTime()
      }, [])

  const totalStopTime = useMemo(()=>{
        if(stopTime === undefined) return 0
        return (
            stopTime.reduce(
                (acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr.stopTime),
                0
              )
        )
    }, [stopTime])

    return (
        <div>
            total stop time: {totalStopTime}
        </div>
    )
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Hope this helps!